# Retriving radiobutton list from session

Tags: c#, asp.net

Retriving radiobutton list selection from session. I have a radiobutton list. I want to have what I selected when I return to the page. The radiobutton list is filled from a array of strings

Adding selection to the session

```
                  Session["selection"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex;
```

page load

```
                    if (!IsPostBack)
                    {
                    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = (string)Session["selection"];
                    }
```

Not working not sure why

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN: [`ListControl.SelectedIndex Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets the lowest ordinal index of the selected items in the
>   list.

Try This:

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["selection"]);
```